# Why does my directional light only rotate from 90º to -90º (Unity 5.5)

Tags: c#, rotation, unity-game-engine, euler-angles

I have tried both of these C#scripts  to rotate my directional light:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class LightRotator : MonoBehaviour
{

    void Update ()
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.eulerAngles.x + 1.0f,
                                              transform.eulerAngles.y, 
                                              transform.eulerAngles.z);
    }
}
```

and

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class LightRotator : MonoBehaviour
{

    void Update ()
    {    
        transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(transform.localEulerAngles.x + 1.0f, 
                                                 transform.localEulerAngles.y, 
                                                 transform.localEulerAngles.z);
    }
}
```

They both seem to function exactly the same: If I change `transform.eulerAngles.y` to `transform.eulerAngles.y + 0.5f`, the light will rotate along the y-axis, and the same works for the z-axis. However, when I try to do this with the x-axis, it will rotate until it hits 90º, at which point it will continue to attempt rotation but it immediately and continuously shoved back to 90º. If I reverse the direction, it does the same thing at -90º. For example, the rotation might be: 88.5,89.0,89.5,90.0, 90.5, 89.93, 90.24, 89.4, etc.

What is causing this clamping and how do I fix it?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not able to reproduce the issue given the information that you've provided. Any chance you could provide short, self-contained example code?

Comment: [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @rutter I added the complete scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/187073/rotation-locks-at-90-or-270-degrees.html

Comment: That seems to be my problem, but does not tell me how to fix it. Also, I tried transform,rotate and it wouldn't rotate at all in any direction. I believe transform only works for position and scale.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html
To be more exact this: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-w.html

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix your problem, you need to use an additional vector, change it inside Update every frame, and then pass it to the `eulerAngles` propriety of the transform.

```
Vector3 vect = Vector3.zero;
float rotationSpeed = 10f;

void Start () {
    vect = transform.eulerAngles; //Set the vect rotation equal to the game object's one
}

void Update ()
{
    vect.x += rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

    //Pass unique eulerAngles representation to the object without letting Unity change it
    transform.eulerAngles = vect;
}
```

This happens btw because there're multiple euler angles representation of a single physical rotation in the 3D space, and when you work directly on the `eulerAngles` propriety of the transform, Unity makes some work behind the scenes, which can lead to a gimbal lock.

Answer (score 0):

Use Quaternions.  It's what Unity3d uses internally and doesn't have any of the side effects of euler angles.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class LightRotator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 RotationAxis = Vector3.right;

    Quaternion _startRotation;
    float _rotationIncrement = 0;
    void Start()
    {
         _startRotation = transform.rotation;
    }
    void Update ()
    {
        Quaternion rotationMod = 
            Quaternion.AngleAxis(_rotationIncrement, RotationAxis);
        _rotationIncrement += 1;
        transform.rotation = _startRotation * rotationMod;
    }
}
```

However, you probably want to use something like `Quaternion.RotateTowards` or `Quaternion.Lerp` along with `Time.time` and a rate.  You will get much smoother results that way.

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to rotate along the X-axis then set the other axis as 0.